# How to connect openshift Phpmyadmin database using Nodejs Server?

Tags: node.js, openshift

> How to connect **"openshift phpmyadmin database"** using nodejs server
>   Below is my code ... I am not getting result from the database ...
>
> log :
>   Success{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":2,"warningCo
>   unt":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}

```
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({

    OPENSHIFT_NAMMAOORU_DB_HOST :'127.4.188.2',
    OPENSHIFT_NAMMAOORU_DB_PORT :'3306',
    OPENSHIFT_NAMMAOORU_DB_USERNAME:'adminfxxxxx',
    OPENSHIFT_NAMMAOORU_DB_PASSWORD:'xxxxxxxxx',
    OPENSHIFT_NAMMAOORU_DB_URL:'mysql://adminxxxx:xxxxxxx@127.4.188.2:3306',


    //database:'nammaooru'


    });


    connection.connect(function(err,success){
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      console.log("Error"+JSON.strinerr);

      }
      else
      {
        console.log("Success"+JSON.stringify(success));
      }
    });

app.get('/city',function(req,res){
try{



  //var id = req.query.id;

/*var t=req.query.id;
console.log(t);
*/  /*  var data = {
        "error":1,
        "Books":""
    };*/


    console.log(req.params.cityid);
    var t=1;
    connection.query("SELECT * from city",function(err, rows, fields){

console.log("success"+JSON.stringify(rows));

//console.log("success"+JSON.stringify(fields));
//console.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
//console.log("success"+JSON.stringify(err));

    });

}
catch(e)
{
console.log(e); 
}

});
```

Local Rest url **http://localhost:8000/city**

> { code: "ER_NO_DB_ERROR", errno: 1046, sqlState: "3D000", index: 0 }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are creating the mysql connection properly:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.4.188.2',
    user: 'adminfxxxxx'',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    port: 3306
});
```

Comment: if i try this i am getting Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'adminxxxxxx'@'
@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)

Comment: Check the permissions granted for that user. Go to a command line and run `mysql`. Then run: `show grants for 'adminfxxxxx'@'%';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this just add database name as below

var connection = mysql.createConnection({

```
host :'127.4.188.2',
port :'3306', // if this doesn't work try removing port once
user:'adminfxxxxx',
password:'xxxxxxxxx',
database:'xxxxxxxxx', //specify database Name
```